# Avoiding Copy-Paste code initialising a series of SDL_Rects in a Struct

Tags: c++, boost, sdl

I've got a struct for defining the graphics of a feature in my 2D engine. In that, there are a series of SDL_Rects called "middle, left_edge, top_left_corner" etc. In part of my code, I'm initialising them off a series of arguments types into the scripting engine/command line, that are stored as a vector of std::strings.

As a matter of style, and avoiding stupid mistakes due to repetition (and having to correct any mistakes 9 times), is there any way to clean up this code? Or would this be reasonable?

```
//RectZeroes is just an SDL_Rect of {0,0,0,0} to ensure that it is initialised

        SDL_Rect middle = RectZeroes;
        if (args.size() >= 6 ) 
        {
            middle.x = boost::lexical_cast<int>(args[3]); 
            middle.y = boost::lexical_cast<int>(args[4]);
            middle.w = boost::lexical_cast<int>(args[5]);
            middle.h = boost::lexical_cast<int>(args[6]);
        }

        SDL_Rect left_edge = RectZeroes;
        if (args.size() >= 10 ) 
        {
            left_edge.x = boost::lexical_cast<int>(args[7]); 
            left_edge.y = boost::lexical_cast<int>(args[8]);
            left_edge.w = boost::lexical_cast<int>(args[9]);
            left_edge.h = boost::lexical_cast<int>(args[10]);
        }
//And so on
```

Comment: I know it sounds like a silly question - but I always get nervous when my programming feels like I'm doing the work of Word's "Form Printing"

Comment: Can you post a sample script code which initializes the rectangles?

Comment: Bank AddFeatureStyle "Descriptor" "LeftTrayEdge.png" 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38   - Its a simple script language I've done for it (more of a command line style interpreter then anything else)  - everything after that initial 3 is rectangles. The script isn't necessarily going to be nicely human readable - its likely I'll write a little CSV->MyDodgyScript converter for formy bits like this so I can use an actual spreadsheet with tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this isn’t a pleasant code. To avoid the repetition, do the same as always in programming: *encapsulate* – in this case, encapsulate the structure and giving it a proper constructor, and write a thin wrapper around `boost::lexical_cast<int>(x)`.

Or, if you want to avoid wrapping `SDL_Rect` then write an initialiser function:

```
template <typename TString>
int parse_int(TString const& value) { return boost::lexical_cast<int>(value); }

void init_sdl_rect_from_args(
    SDL_Rect& rect, std::vector<std::string> const& args, unsigned offset)
{
    rect.x = parse_int(args[offset + 0]);
    rect.y = parse_int(args[offset + 1]);
    rect.w = parse_int(args[offset + 2]);
    rect.h = parse_int(args[offset + 3]);
}
```

And then:

```
SDL_Rect middle = RectZeroes;
if (args.size() >= 6)
    init_sdl_rect_from_args(middle, args, 3);

SDL_Rect left_edge = RectZeroes;
if (args.size() >= 10)
    init_sdl_rect_from_args(left_edge, args, 7);
```

Better yet, make the initialiser *return* the constructed structure. This makes it even more convenient to use (namely, in an initialiser):

```
SDL_Rect rect_from_args(std::vector<std::string> const& args, unsigned offset) {
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = parse_int(args[offset + 0]);
    rect.y = parse_int(args[offset + 1]);
    rect.w = parse_int(args[offset + 2]);
    rect.h = parse_int(args[offset + 3]);
    return rect;
}

SDL_Rect middle = (args.size() >= 6) ? rect_from_args(args, 3) : RectZeroes;
SDL_Rect left_edge = (args.size() >= 10) ? rect_from_args(args, 7) : RectZeroes;
```

Comment: Why this has to be a macro? Why not just a function `SDL_Rect stringsToRect(vector<string> v, int offset)`?

Comment: @Banthar Because I’m an idiot. See update. My addled brain originally wanted to make use of Boost.PP (`BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I`) to fold the four init statements into a single one but this doesn’t actually improve the code by much, nor even make it considerably shorter.

Comment: I think I understand why the former is the preferred solution... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @lochok See update for even better code. I should go back to bed, clearly my head isn’t working properly today.